# robot_localization (fake) IMU + gps setup Error

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am working on getting the robot_localization package up and running to estimate pose using an IMU and a gps, but I'm having a bit of trouble. I've read through the whole [docs](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/configuring_robot_localization.html#) and I'm still getting an error:

```
[ERROR] [1613686575.266536469]: Could not obtain transform from odom->base_link
[ WARN] [1613686575.592023869]: Could not obtain map->base_link transform. Will not remove offset of navsat device from robots origin.
[ WARN] [1613686576.692104170]: Could not obtain transform from base_link to map. Error was "map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

Currently I'm generating fake gps and imu data over `/gps/fix` and `/imu/data` with with the following code (simplified):

```
def main(args=None):
    rospy.init_node('gps_imu_node', anonymous=True)

    gps_pub = rospy.Publisher('gps/fix', NavSatFix, queue_size=10)
    imu_pub = rospy.Publisher('imu/data', Imu, queue_size=10)
    
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        # GPS
        msg = NavSatFix()
        msg.header = Header()
        msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        msg.header.frame_id = "base_link"

        # Position in degrees.
        msg.latitude = 57.047218
        msg.longitude = 9.920100

        gps_pub.publish(msg)

        # IMU
        msg = Imu()
        msg.header = Header()
        msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        msg.header.frame_id = "base_link"

        imu_pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()
```

I'm filling it with data, but for example's sake I've taken that out, as that's not related to my error (I don't think).

Additionally, I'm running the `navsat_transform_node` with the following paramaters:

```
<launch>
 <!-- -->
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true">

    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0"/>
    <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
    <param name="zero_altitude" value="true"/>


    <param name="broadcast_cartesian_transform" value="false"/>
    <param name="publish_filtered_gps" value="true"/>


    <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="false"/>
    <param name="wait_for_datum" value="false"/>


    <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu/data" />
    <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/gps/fix" />
    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered" />

  </node>

</launch>
```

And I'm running `ekf_localization_node` with the following yaml config file:

```
frequency: 50

two_d_mode: true

publish_tf: true

odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: map
map_frame: map

imu0: /imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              true, false, false]
imu0_differential: false

odom0: /odometry/gps
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false

process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]


initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                                                      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

I feel like I have set everything up properly, but something is obviously breaking when I'm trying to link my tf frames together. There's no output on the `/tf` topic either, which makes me suspicious that something is setup wrong. I have confirmed my fake imu & gps topics are publishing, but nothing else seems to be.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be super appreciative. I've been crawling forum posts all day and can't seem to find someone with my same issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372191/robot_localization-(fake)-imu-+-gps-setup-error/) by [tdoe321](https://answers.ros.org/users/52685/tdoe321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Moving all the comments to a complete answer:

1.Change `world_frame: odom` so the EKF publishes the `odom→base_link` transform. If world frame is set to map it will publish `map→odom` transform and you will need something else generating the `odom->base_link` transform

2.Publish a static tf between `map->odom` such as a null rotation RPY(0,0,0):

```
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom" />
```

3.Make sure you fill up the covariance diagonal values of the sensor messages. The covariances indicates the confidence of a measurement and the filter weights the covariances to integrate those measurements. If there are no covariances the filter will not perform as expected.

4.Fill up your IMU message at least with the orientation. If it its for testing purposes set the orientation to (0,0,0), which in quaternions is:

```
imu_msg.orientation.x = 0
imu_msg.orientation.y = 0
imu_msg.orientation.z = 0
imu_msg.orientation.w = 1
```

5.Change `odom0_config` to (in case you do not measure height and or two_d_mode=true):

```
odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                     false, false, false,
                     false false, false,
                     false, false, false,
                     false, false, false]
```

6.If you are not populating the IMU msg with angular rate and linear accelerations, I would suggest you set imu0_config lines 4 and 5 to false.

---

Originally posted by [xaru8145](https://answers.ros.org/users/46622/xaru8145/) with karma: 105 on 2021-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1